# Hiding columns with bootstrap using angular ui.grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I need to use ui-grid in angular js and I was doing a little test to hide the columns based on bootstrap classes. For exampl consider having a table with 100 columns but on mobile you want to show only 3 of them.

This is a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/9TGp1vPZeOfKLjzezgUv?p=preview

I'm using:

```
cellClass:"hidden-sm",headerCellClass:"hidden-sm"
```

as you see the column is not shown but the grid is still taking all the space.

Any help?

Comment: Do u add the cell class dynamically?

Comment: It's programmatic in the grid options

Answer (score 0):

ui grid just doesn't seem to support resizing using css. You have to use its own methods to set visibility.

```
    function setColumnVisibility() {
        if (($(window).width()) <= 768) {
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].visible = false;
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[2].visible = false;
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[4].visible = false;
        }

        if (($(window).width()) <= 992) {
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[5].visible = false;
            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[7].visible = false;
        }
    }

    setColumnVisibility();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setColumnVisibility();
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `visible:false` property on the column to make it completely hide.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cj4yvmEEnrcziKl6FdyX?p=preview

Comment: In this way the column wouldn't be visible in any device. I need it visible on large desktop, for example